# jQuery Available Time Picker

Tags: jquery, html, forms, formatting

this is more for advice rather than a specific question.

I am looking into ways to create an available time grid for users to set. I want users to be able to choose which hour slots they are available for each day of the week for every hour of the day.

Is there an elegant jQuery tool that anyone knows of that can do this?

The best I can come up with is a grid of nicely styed tick boxes for each hour aligned to each day...

I almost want this to look like the Windows parental control time grid and I have a feeling there are going to be no shortcuts on this one...

Comment: did you by any chance found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I use this one: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

Check the demos, to see if this what you are looking for: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/demos

Comment: Do you know if that can be made to be just a generic week with no dates?

Comment: I think so. You could hide/disable all the buttons & labels that are date-specific. Some of them you can simply disable through settings [https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Script-options](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Script-options) (like `buttons: false` for hidding button panel) but for hiding date labels etc. you will need to change the source of plugin itself [https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/master/jquery.weekcalendar.js](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/master/jquery.weekcalendar.js)